# Intersection of two lists with different formats

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following two lists:

```
l1 = {{"apple", "banana", "cream"}, {"beef", "pepper", 
   "salt"}, {"wine", "beer", "beef", "olive"}}
l2 = {"beef:salt:pepper", "apple:cream", "wine:beer:beef:olive"}
```

For each element in `l2` I want to go through `l1` and select the element in `l2` if it exists in `l1`, such that the output would be:

```
{"beef:salt:pepper", "wine:beer:beef:olive"}
```

I know generally one should use `Intersection[l1, l2]` yet the format of two lists are different so it turns an empty list. I wonder how one go around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reformat `l2`, so that you have it in the same format as `l1`, using `StringSplit`:

```
reformatted = StringSplit[#, ":"] & /@ l2
```

> `{{"beef", "salt", "pepper"}, {"apple", "cream"}, {"wine", "beer",
>
>   "beef", "olive"}}`

```
Intersection[l1, reformatted]
```

> `{{"wine", "beer", "beef", "olive"}}`

You'll notice that `{"beef", "pepper", "salt"}` was left out, because order matters. If you don't want to consider the order in which elements appear, you can fix it like this:

```
Intersection[l1, reformatted, SameTest -> (Sort[#1] === Sort[#2] &)]
```

> `{{"beef", "pepper", "salt"}, {"wine", "beer", "beef", "olive"}}`

Comment: One could also include the reformatting directly in the `SameTest`, which would allow to work directly with the original lists